# Error: This version of PyQt5 requires sip 4.19.1 or later

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5

I'm trying to build PyQt5 however, i keep getting the error that it requires sip 4.19.1 or later.

I've tried using "--sip", "--sipdir" and "--sip-incdir" however none of these seem to work.

I installed sip by running "python configure.py" -> "nmake" -> "nmake install" and there were no errors while running these.

```
C:\Users\Tarzan\Downloads\sip-4.19.2>nmake install

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd sipgen
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" install

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        copy /y sip.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\sip.exe
        1 file(s) copied.
        cd siplib
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" install

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        copy /y sip.pyd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyd
        1 file(s) copied.
        copy /y C:\Users\Tarzan\Downloads\sip-4.19.2\siplib\sip.h C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\sip.h
        1 file(s) copied.
        copy /y C:\Users\Tarzan\Downloads\sip-4.19.2\sip.pyi C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyi
        1 file(s) copied.
        copy /y sipconfig.py C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py
        1 file(s) copied.
        copy /y C:\Users\Tarzan\Downloads\sip-4.19.2\sipdistutils.py C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sipdistutils.py
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Below is an attempt at running the config file

```
C:\Users\Tarzan\Downloads\PyQt5_gpl-5.8.2>python configure.py
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.8.2 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.6.0 on win32.

Type 'L' to view the license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Error: This version of PyQt5 requires sip 4.19.1 or later.
```

I've been googling about an hour or two now and none of the solutions posted seems to have worked.

NB: Used Visual C++ 2015 x64 Native Build Tools Command Promt

Comment: Did you use the VC++ command prompt for both SIP and PyQt? What is the output if you type `where python`? SIP is being installed into the Anaconda directory, maybe you have another python installation on the system, eg C:\Python36.

Comment: @user3419537 Thanks for reply. Yes i used the same VC++ cmd for both SIP and PyQt. The output when i typed where python was `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe` Also I've got no other python installed currently.

Comment: What about if you `import sip` from python and print `sip.SIP_VERSION_STR`?

Comment: @user3419537 it prints `4.19.2`

Comment: Try pointing PyQt's `configure.py` to the right sip via `--sip` (or make sure that sip is the first one in your PATH)

Comment: @TheCompiler thanks, i tried doing that before, but i guess i choose the wrong sip file or something? It appears to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when i tried running `python configure.py --sip <path>` i had choosen the wrong path from before. Now it is however working.